# JSF 2.0 authentication

Tags: authentication, tomcat, jsf-2, authorization

I know there are a lot of other question about this topic but I haven't found the right solution for my case.

The landscape is like that:
Backend runs on a tomcat and provides some services. Amongst others there is UserService.login().

The Frontend (JSF 2.0, Spring 3, OpenFaces or Primefaces) which i should implement runs on a different tomcat. I need to implement the security level in the frontend. For sure I'm searching for the best framework (seam, spring security, jaas). And if you know a good tutorial it would be great if you let me know. i can send username/password to the backend and receive a User with id, username and role.

I found lots of tutorials, but i didn't get it work properly. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I probably can't explain the whole thing. But you can follow these links and should get you want you need.

First setup basic JSF-Spring Security application like in this [link](http://janistoolbox.typepad.com/blog/2010/03/j2ee-security-java-serverfaces-jsf-spring-security.html) . Here the author did hard code the user details in the applicationContext itself for simplicity. But for your requirement you need to implement a custom UserDetailsService and which is the authentication provider where it loads the user details from the backend. You can take a look at this [link](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_3065.html).